# Read, and then split a text file into different arrays

Tags: java

So I'm trying to use a BufferedReader to split a text file into 2 different arrays, I've written some code but I'm not sure where to go from here.

I know how to populate an array, but i just cant seem to get the specific lines.

So, one array for NEW_OFFICE containing only the numbers, and one for MAIN_ADDRESS containing only the numbers below it.

```
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myDelivery.txt"));
    String read = null;
    while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String words = read.split("NEW_OFFICE")[0];
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored) { }
}
```

This is the text file:

```
NEW_OFFICE
-92.48392883    52.96531732
-2.483984994    92.48392883
MAIN_ADDRESS
-1.207614869    52.98908196
```

Comment: Is `NEW_OFFICE` always the first line in the file? Is there an unknown number of lines in the file between `NEW_OFFICE` and `MAIN_ADDRESS` ? Can `NEW_OFFICE` appear in the file more than once? Can `MAIN_ADDRESS` appear in the file more than once?

Comment: NEW_OFFICE always is the first line, and always has two lines below it, the same goes for MAIN_ADDRESS it always has one line below it. NEW_OFFICE & MAIN_ADDRESS can't appear more than once.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post what should be the contents of each of the two arrays that you want to create from the data in the text file. Should the first array have the following four elements: -92.48392883 , 52.96531732 , -2.483984994 , 92.48392883

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NEW_OFFICE always is the first line, and always has two lines below
>   it, the same goes for MAIN_ADDRESS it always has one line below it.
>   NEW_OFFICE & MAIN_ADDRESS can't appear more than once.

Based on your comment mentioned above, given below is the solution:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[][] office = new String[2][2];
        String[][] main = new String[1][2];
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myDelivery.txt"))) {
            String read;
            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (read.equalsIgnoreCase("NEW_OFFICE")) {
                    // Read next two lines
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        if ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            office[i] = read.split("\\s+");
                        }
                    }
                } else if (read.equalsIgnoreCase("MAIN_ADDRESS")) {
                    // Read next line
                    if ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        main[0] = read.split("\\s+");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Display office[][]
        System.out.println("Displaying office:");
        for (String[] officeData : office) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(officeData));
        }

        // Display main[][]
        System.out.println("Displaying main:");
        for (String[] mainData : main) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mainData));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Displaying office:
[-92.48392883, 52.96531732]
[-2.483984994, 92.48392883]
Displaying main:
[-1.207614869, 52.98908196]
```

**Notes:**

1. `\\s+` is for splitting the line on space(s).
2. Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to simplify your code.

Comment: Can I message you in private? I had a question about an error I'm getting when I change some stuff...

Answer (score 0):

`.split()` does take a string, but it should be a regex, not the substring that you want to split it on. You want to change your code like this:

```
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("x.txt"))) {
    String read;
    String office = "";
    while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (read.contains("NEW_OFFICE")) {
            office = "NEW_OFFICE";
        } else if (read.contains("MAIN_ADDRESS")) {
            office = "MAIN_ADDRESS";
        } else {
            System.out.println(office + " : " + read);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have also changed your `try` with `try-with-resources` so you don't have to worry about closing the resource.

Comment: How do I read the numbers below it? And then assign these numbers into an array according to the header.

Comment: In the else, you have the name of the `office` and the value in the `read`. Use that to fill an array as you seem fit.

Comment: For further questions, please take this working code and create a new post if you are not able to populate the array. This question was on finding the lines and that is answered. Read here why: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: You may also want to accept the answer by clicking the tick on the left side of the answer for future readers. You will also get 2 rep points for accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I´d go with somethin like this.
Please be aware that I don´t have an IDE right now so this is basically pseudo code:

```
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("x.txt"))) {
    String line = null;
    boolean isOffice = false;
    ArrayList<double> officeInts = new ArrayList<double>();
    ArrayList<double> addressInts = new ArrayList<double>();
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("NEW_OFFICE")) {
            isOffice = true;
            continue;
        } else if (line.contains("MAIN_ADDRESS")) {
            isOffice = false;
            continue;
        }

        for(String s : line.split("    "){
            double num = Double.parseDouble(s);
            if(isOffice) {
                officeInts.add(num);
            } else {
                addressInts.add(num);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```